# Why does my USB hub hide a directly attached drive from the boot menu? (post-Filevault)

Tags: usb, startup, filevault

I recently enabled FileVault on both my mid-2012 Retina MacBook Pro and my external USB drive containing a Carbon Copy Cloner backup.

My external drive is attached directly to the MBP. I also have a powered USB hub attached to the MBP's *other* USB port (no drives are attached to the hub).

Since enabling FileVault, I've noticed a peculiar behavior on the boot menu (holding option at startup):

- If I leave the hub attached during startup, the CCC drive doesn't show up in the boot menu.
- If I leave the hub unplugged during startup, the CCC drive shows up.
- Swapping the USB ports for the drive and hub changes nothing.

Any ideas what the cause of this might be?

(Side note: I've also noticed that both the internal recovery partition and CCC's recovery partition are missing from the menu. But that's apparently normal from what I've researched.)

Answer (score 1):

Its because the hub is able to connect drives so the hub shows it similar to how an empty optical drive shows up.